# Time (number of months from a baseline) is a numeric or a categorical variable?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, anova, panel-data

I want to put time into a linear mixed-effects model. I have 4 time-points: baseline assessment (time = 0), first assessment (after 12 months), second assessment (after 24 months), and a third assessment (after 36 months). So assessments are evenly spared across this 36-months time period. My outcome variable is a numeric score and I want to know how and if this outcome is affected by the progression of time.

I am undecided whether this should be treated as a numeric continuous or categorical variable. What do you suggest?

many thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what difference your decision might make?  What exactly would be implied by "treating" the time points as categorical instead of numerical?

Comment: the point is to use ANOVA (time as categorical) or a regression (time as numeric).

Comment: Right: that's an issue of how to *model* your data.  Although it's valid to frame it in the language of data types, I would suggest that such language misses the point and might make it more difficult to devise an effective solution.  Indeed, once we have framed your situation in terms of model selection, that opens it up to a rich set of standard methods of model identification.